# Display Number on Marker for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

All,
I've got the following code to display my markers on my maps:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script  type="text/javascript">
function addLoadEvent(func) { 
var oldonload = window.onload; 
if (typeof window.onload != 'function'){ 
    window.onload = func
} else { 
    window.onload = function() {
        oldonload();
        func();
    }
}
}

var map,
    infowin=new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'moin'});
function loadMap() 
{
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'),
    {   
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_SESSION['pav_event_latitude']; ?>, 
                                    <?php echo $_SESSION['pav_event_longitude']; ?>)
    });

  addPoints(myStores);
}

function addPoints( points )
{  
  var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for ( var p = 0; p < points.length; ++p )
  {
    var pointData = points[p];
    if ( pointData == null ) {map.fitBounds(bounds);return; }
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng( pointData.latitude, pointData.longitude );
    bounds.union(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(point));
    createMarker( point,  pointData.html );
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}

function createMarker(point,  popuphtml) 
{
  var popuphtml = "<div id=\"popup\">" + popuphtml + "<\/div>";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
      position:point,
      map:map
    }
  );
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowin.setContent(popuphtml)
      infowin.open(map,marker);
    });

}
function Store( lat, long, text )
{
    this.latitude = lat;
    this.longitude = long;
    this.html = text;
}

var myStores = [<?php echo $jsData;?>, null];
addLoadEvent(loadMap);
</script>
```

This works great. However I'm trying to say add a number over the marker so that people can relate the number on my site with the marker in Google Maps. How can I go about creating the number over top of my markers (on top of the actual icon and not in an information bubble)?

Any help would be greatly appreciate! Thanks in advance!

Comment: click on the marker link we can  give the number?but i don't find ways to have overlay number on icon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**: This API is now deprecated, and I can no longer recommend this answer.

---

You could use Google's Charts API to generate a pin image.

See: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons.html#pins

It'll make and return an image of a marker from the parameters you specify. An example usage would be: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2|FF776B|000000

To implement it into your Google Map, it can be added into the new Marker() code:

```
var number = 2; // or whatever you want to do here
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position:point,
        map:map,
        icon:'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='+number+'|FF776B|000000',
        shadow:'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow'
    }
);
```

Comment: This works great but how can I pass my createMarker function a dynamic variable of which number to display? That works great if you hard code in the number 2 but I'm not sure how to pass in the correct number to the function.

Comment: @user1048676 To start with it looks like you could add another parameter to your `addMarker()` function, so it becomes something `function createMarker(point,  popuphtml, number)`. As for where you get the number to pass in, you could use the `p` iterator in the `addPoints` function. So, `createMarker( point,  pointData.html, p );` However, if you need the number to be consistent with your PHP (eg. if that's outputting somewhere else on the page, which it sounds like), then you may need to reflect that in your `<?php echo $jsData; ?>`, and use a number property, passing it in like the html.

Comment: @Rick while that's a good solution, the [Infographics portion of Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/) (your link above) has officially been deprecated.

Comment: @John Wow, deprecated only two months after my answer apparently. Talk about bad timing. Thanks for pointing that out; I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

For quite some time now, map markers have an option called `label` available.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:point,
    map:map,
    label: "Your text here."
});
```

Labels themselves have few options to play with. You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerLabel).

---

**Original answer**

<strike>[Here](http://markericons.eu) is a service similar to one described by Rick - but still active and you can upload your own marker image.</strike>

Service is no longer available.