# Custom icon marker with dynamic numbering for Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I have seen many examples for dynamically generating numbers on the marker icons.
One of them i found is google chart apis.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407886/display-number-on-marker-for-google-maps) partially solved my problem. I was able to generate number after editing my code as shown below. 
But is it possible to add a custom icon like this [image]
 and then do generate number over it?

```
function addMarker(id,location,address,facility,name,ratings) 
    {


        marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: location,
            map: map,
            animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='+id+'|FF776B|000000',
             shadow:'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow'
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This chart api is deprecated now and google will provide support for only one year according to their revised "Terms and conditions".

I think the best way is to create your markers on the server side. If your application needs to show a limited number of markers (say 25 max at a time) then you can have them on the server. Image processing tools are available in Java or any other programming language.

Here is a short snippet using java.

```
BufferedImage image = null;
try {
   image = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/base/icon"));
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
g.drawString("1", x, y);  // x,y are points where you want to add the number
g.dispose();

try {
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can use a for loop to create as many numbered markers you want.