# Google Maps: addPoints is not defined and too much recursion

Tags: javascript, html, maps

if I use the code shown below:
1) It works fine for a few seconds than, Google removes the map and replacing it with an error message (oops! error.. see console logs for more info).
2) If I create a test file such as test.html, and paste my code, it works fine without any issue.
3) But if I use it in my page It doesn't work (see 1)

I use jquery-ui, jquery and fancybox.. I deleted those scripts and tested again in my page, same issue!

Console logs show me:
addPoints is not defined
too much recursion

My code

```js
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=my-key" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
// Google Map Maker script v.3
// (c) 2012 Richard Stephenson http://www.rpsdigital.com
// http://mapmaker.donkeymagic.co.uk
var map;
var icon0;
var newPoints = new Array();
 
function addLoadEvent(func) { 
 var oldonload = window.onload; 
 if (typeof window.onload != 'function'){ 
  window.onload = func
 } else { 
  window.onload = function() {
   oldonload();
   func();
  }
 }
}
 
addLoadEvent(loadMap);
addLoadEvent(addPoints);
 
function loadMap() {
 map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
 map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
 map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
  map.addMapType(G_PHYSICAL_MAP);
  map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
 map.setCenter(new GLatLng( 46.198308213008495, 14.969000816345215), 7);
 map.setMapType(G_PHYSICAL_MAP);
 
 

 for(var i = 0; i < newPoints.length; i++) {
  var point = new GPoint(newPoints[i][1],newPoints[i][0]);
  var popuphtml = newPoints[i][4] ;
  var marker = createMarker(point,newPoints[i][2],popuphtml);
  map.addOverlay(marker);
 }
}
 
function createMarker(point, icon, popuphtml) {
 var popuphtml = "<div id=\"popup\">" + popuphtml + "<\/div>";
 var marker = new GMarker(point, icon);
 GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
  marker.openInfoWindowHtml(popuphtml);
 });
 return marker;
}
//]]>
</script>

<div id="map" style="width:330px;height:300px"></div>
```

Comment: Is that all the code? Because addPoints is not defined here and I didn't find a function addPoints in google maps api by a simple google search (is there such a function there?)

Comment: Yes, its the code. I think addPoints defining in Google Maps script. You can see it in action: http://www.slovenija.nl/. If you save the code in a test file html.test, it works fine.. you dont need to create any head body tag..

Comment: Can you share the code in the test file as well? You mentioned it's working in a test file - how is that code different than the code you shared here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as the console is trying to tell you, that the addPoints function is not defined.

Why does the behaviour happen exactly the way it does I cannot say - probably because your function loadMap doesn't really use addPoints and addPoints (an undefined var/reference in this code) is called only after your loadMap function is called upon the load event dispatch, as it is added only after loadMap is added. So once it is reached the code stops to work.

In your code addPoints is not defined and as I wrote in a comment to your question - I couldn't find it in the google maps api docs.
From a google search I found addPoints in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407886/display-number-on-marker-for-google-maps) which looks very much like your code.
I am guessing you used that code or a similar one to build your tool but deleted the addPoints function definition at some point in time.

As you don't seem to use addPoints at all (it isn't defined in your code) I suggest you just delete the line

```
addLoadEvent(addPoints);
```

and I predict the problem will go away.

Comment: I have already deleted addLoadEvent(addPoints); line.. it doesn't work. You can test it yourself, just create a test.html file and paste my code without any other tag such as HEAD, BODY etc.. just paste the code and run the file.. it works fine!

Comment: Finally I found the issue: It was due the API key! I was trying to use it on another domain that's why Google blocks it! Thank you for your answer it helped me :)